# Make a text loop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I'd like make something with jQuery but it doesn't work properly.

Here my html markup:

```
<div class="addv" data-plus="Execution capability both in Europe and Asia, ensuring 24/7 reactivity">
   Reactivity &amp; Proactivity
</div>

<div class="addv" data-plus="Prestigious MNCs : Over 70% LOI signed,Over 60% of closing">
   Track Record
</div>

<div class="addv-central">
   Transaction Excellence
</div>

<div class="addv" data-plus="Over 5,000 firms and 500 PE HNWI, family office in our « in house » databases">
   Our proprietary Databases
</div>

<div class="addv" data-plus="Multicultural team posses the solid expertise in our key sectors and countries">
   Sector &amp; Country Expertise
</div>
```

Here my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addv").each(function(i, current){
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".addv-central").text($(".addv").data("plus"));
    }, 2000);   
});
```

I want to make appear the text located in the divs ".adv" in "adv-central"
I'm trying to do it with a "loop" (each + setIntervall) but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `setInterval` for each your element, you should call it just once and loop through elements.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var $elems = $('.addv');
    var length = $elems.length;

    setInterval(function () {
        $elems
            .removeClass('active')
            .eq(i++ % length)
                .addClass('active')
                .css('opacity', 0).animate({'opacity': 1});

    }, 1000);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.addv {
    display: none;
}

.addv.active {
    display: block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pz9aw6t/).

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `});` at the end of jquery code

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttmv6bjn/3/)

if you want to `merge` all `addv` div `data-plus` property value to `addv-central` 
you must use `setinterval` before `.each` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        centralData = "";
        $(".addv").each(function(i, current){
        centralData += $(current).data("plus") ;          
        });
        $(".addv-central").text(centralData); 
    }, 2000); 
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttmv6bjn/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable and `.eq()` to select desired element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataP = $('.addv');
    var cnt = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        cnt==dataP.length-1?cnt=0:cnt++;
        $('.addv-central').text(dataP.eq(cnt).data('plus'));
    },2000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydgq7LLm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what your are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dataPlus = '';

    $(".addv").each(function (i, current) {
        dataPlus = dataPlus + "," + $(current).data("plus");
    });

    $(".addv-central").text(dataPlus);

});
```